# unable to draw polygon without attribute window popping up?

Tags: qgis, vector, digitizing

I'm fairly new to QGIS and an trying to draw a polygon via "Adding Feature". When I make the first left click to start, the attribute window pops up instead of letting me continue on with additional points. [These instructions](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer) don't seem to offer a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings - Options, digitizing tab. Tick "Suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation".